# Starting with anaconda on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I installed latest version of Anaconda3-2020-02.
I was trying to follow [this](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-python) instruction in order to create environment for running with `python==3.6` instead of `python==3.7.`, because I have python 3.6. installed.
So, running the

```
conda create --name snakes python=3.6
```

and then activating my environment with `conda activate snakes`, it enters environment `(snakes)`. However there are no anaconda packages inside like `jupyter notebook` or others, no `anaconda-navigator`... So whats the purpose of it and **how can I run these programs from environment**?
Also, for some reason (when I am **not in the environment**, just regular bash shell) `$PATH` is not set up to the `/bin` directory in anaconda, just to `/condabin`. Can you explain this also, because **I am not able to run nothing except** `conda` command from shell after recommended installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by default after installation environment is not activated, you should activate it by sourcing a file `anaconda3/bin/activate`. You will see indicator `(base)` on the left of your bash prompt.

Good thing about **anaconda3-2020-02** is that it is not messing with system python, as newest python is being launched inside environment and proper`$PATH` is set up just inside environment. If only, for some reason, specific version of python is needed, then it makes sense to set it up with [this](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-python) instruction. I would be just using default one with python 3.7 probably from `(base)` environment.

Keep in mind that by default anaconda components are not being set up inside new environment being created. In order to bring them, for example `jupyter`, you should run the command like this:

```
conda create --name snakes python=3.6 jupyter
```